# Enable username and password for Screenly OSE

Tags: pi-3

I modified the configuration file `~/.screenly/screenly.conf`, where I added username and password in the section of the code below.

```
'auth': {
        'user': '',
        'password': ''
    }
```

It is not asking for a username and password when I am try to access the Screenly server using the IP address.

After adding the username and password, I restarted the web server also using the command `pkill -f server.py`, but still it's not asking for any authentication.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Screenly documentation](https://github.com/Screenly/screenly-ose/blob/master/docs/http-basic-authentication.md#configuration) the 'auth' section should look like this:

```
[auth]
; If desired, fill in with appropriate username and password.
user=
password=
```

Update your configuration and restart the server (or reboot the Pi) to activate it.

Comment: I did not have screenly.conf file so I created this file using nano editor in which I added the above lines for user name and password. I rebooted the Pi but it is not working yet. I have settings.py file where I saw the auth section.Adding the password there also does not work .

Comment: `I have settings.py file where I saw the auth section.Adding the password there also does not work` I would undo these changes. That file is part of the screenly program itself.

Comment: @user2870464 how did you install screenly?

Comment: @user2870464 there should be a logfile. Does it say that the configuration file is missing?

Comment: I installed using an image "2018-05-04-Screenly_OSE_4GB.zip". I burnt the image using Etcher software on SD Card. It has config.txt file but it does not have screenly.conf file. Shall I install the latest image now ? I can see the new image on the Screenly website.

Comment: `I installed using an image "2018-05-04-Screenly_OSE_4GB.zip". ` I just downloaded and it actually has a screenly.conf file with an 'auth' section. I think you have been poking around in the wrong place. Try editing with `nano /home/pi/.screenly/screenly.conf`. Make sure you use the correct path. The directory ~/.screenly (note the dot in there!) has several files in it: screenly.conf, screenly.db, latest_screenly_sha and device_id.

Comment: I edited using the command and finally I got the correct file and Auth section. I tried adding password and username.When tried to login the Screenly server, it is giving an error saying Connections are not private. I enabled SSH and SSL but it is still not allowing me to access the screenly asset page.